# Frase umoristica con molteplici antanaclasi

Tags: puns, figures-of-speech

Di recente mi sono imbattuto nella frase umoristica inglese
"Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana"
che ho scoperto essere abbastanza famosa  ([tanto da avere una pagina su wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_flies_like_an_arrow;_fruit_flies_like_a_banana))

Dopo una breve ricerca ho scoperto che si tratta di un sapiente uso della figura retorica dell'[antanaclasi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasi).

L'arguto uso del vocabolario mi ha abbastanza colpito: tralasciando articoli e preposizioni ci sono 2 parole ripetute con 2 significati diversi su un totale di 8 parole totali - ossia un rapporto 50/50.

Così mi sono messo a cercare di ideare qualcosa di simile
in italiano, ma il meglio a cui sono riuscito ad arrivare è

> Verdi  suole leggere messe in re minore; gialle suole leggere messe ai mocassini

e la costruzione non mi soddisfa del tutto (anche perché sono dovuto ricorrere al cognome del famoso compositore ed è una soluzione poco elegante e perché quando la si legge bisogna variare l'accento di "leggere" tra la prima e la seconda parte);
quindi mi chiedevo se qualcuno potrebbe suggerirmi come migliorarla, o
se sono noti altri esempi di frasi umoristiche analoghe a quella inglese qui sopra.

PS:

Se non ricordo male in dialetto friulano sarebbe nota la frase:

"i gà igà i gai"

(traducibile con "hanno legato i galli'),
ma qui io sono interessato a frasi in italiano e non in dialetto.

Comment: *Lascia l'ascia e accetta l'accetta* (Benito Jacovitti).

Comment: Non sono sicuro che suggerirti come migliorare la tua frase rientri nello spirito di questo sito, che è più pensato per risposte oggettive e verificabili. Mentre invece va benissimo la tua richiesta di frasi famose già esistenti (e in genere di approfondimenti in merito).

Comment: @BakerStreet: È veramente Jacovitti il creatore di quel gioco di parole? Comunque qualcosa di simile, e questo interessa anche OP, c'è anche nella “tragedia in due battute” *Quando Lucio lascia l'ascia* di Achille Campanile.

Comment: @Di sicuro era in un fumetto di Jacovitti, pronunciata da un personaggio, poi se Jacovitti l'avesse presa altrove non lo so, forse conosceva e aveva  ampliato la battuta di Campanile, mettendo pure l'accetta, chi può saperlo.

Comment: a proposito di "Lascia l'ascia e accetta l'accetta"
io conoscevo anche l'esistenza della <<forma tripla>>
"Lascia l'ascia  la scia"
ma qui io stavo cercando non di una frase singola con piu` parole che suonano simili mentre son diverse, quanto
di due frasi totalmente diverse dove pero` sono usate le stesse parole che hanno significati diversi e cambiano anche categoria (sostantivo <=> verbo  <=>  aggettivo, etc)

Comment: Allora la risposta di @FedericoPoloni fa esattamente al caso tuo: le migliori crittografie mnemoniche sono proprio quelle in cui, nella doppia lettura, si scambiano oltre che i significati anche le parti del discorso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'è un gioco enigmistico chiamato *frase bisenso* o a volte col più oscuro nome di [crittografia mnemonica](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crittografia_mnemonica) che consiste, appunto, nel trovare un'espressione che si possa leggere interamente in due modi diversi. L'esempio più famoso per dare l'idea è quello di "mezzo minuto di raccoglimento", che è una definizione di "cucchiaino".

Difficilmente si tratta di una frase completa con soggetto, verbo, e oggetto, ma ci sono anche esempi di questo tipo. La pagina di Wikipedia che ho indicato sopra è un buon puntatore per iniziare a cercare.

Comment: Condivido, e aggiungo che nel sito delle pubblicazioni della Biblioteca Enigmistica Italiana (http://www.enignet.it/pubblicazioni-bei/) sono scaricabili alcuni ottimi testi sulle crittografie mnemoniche: almeno un'introduzione tra gli “Opuscoli” e un'ampia “Antologia delle antologie” sotto “Elenchi, repertori e antologie”.